# How do you set a default textColor inside a LinearLayout that contains multiple TextViews?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-text-color

I have a LinearLayout with that has multiple TextViews and want to set up a default global color for that layout only without having to add a `textColor` field inside each TextView. Also, if it's possible, would it also be possible to override the color value by adding it inside the TextView? i.e. If I set blue as a default color and black for a single TextView, would the blue change to black?

Comment: Create a style and set that style to every TextView you have : )

Comment: @hardartcore, there's no difference between your method and setting setTextColor(). OP is trying to avoid individual view assignment.

Comment: @Taslim it really depends of the situation! : ) With no explanation of what exactly is he trying to achieve with these TextView's I don't think there is the best & correct answer!

Comment: @hardartcore, you're right. I might have concluded too hastily. There's really no telling what OP is trying to achieve. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the default global TextView colors, first you can create your own theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the following items:

- `textColorPrimary` - for Large texts
- `textColorSecondary` - for Medium texts
- `textColorTertiary` - for Small texts
- `textColorHint` - for Hint texts

For example, in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<style name="TextViewTheme" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <!-- Set the default global color for TextViews to Holo Blue Dark -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

Next, set the theme style on your LinearLayout. You can also override the default for a single TextView to black color, like the following which set the first TextView Hint text color to black in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/TextViewTheme">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/phone_tv"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_tv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can override default text colors for the entire application by setting textColorPrimary and textColorSecondary in your parent  in styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="textColorSecondary">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late answer but this does the trick.
Inside `style.xml` lately changed to `themes.xml`

```
<style name="ErrorStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Then inside your xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/ErrorStyle">

 .. All of your TextView
</LinearLayout>
```

Using this approach we can use other xml variation such as night mode, etc... and we still have te possibility to override the internal TextViews.

Answer (score 1):

If your TextViews are indeed very many to the extent that calling `setTextColor()` on each of them would be a herculean task, why not use a view that supports an adapter (i.e [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview), [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) etc). Your TextViews would show up the exact same way as you intend them to appear with the LinearLayout.

While using an adapter, you can set up a model TextView layout and set a *global textColor* for all the TextViews. You can override this global textcolor in your adapter by using simple `if` and `else` statements.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

This code will work even if you add or remove TextViews from your layout. Just put it in your activity's `onCreate()`;

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } 
    }
```

change the color to what you like.  
If you want after this code you can change the color for any specific TextView.